# Remove one of 3 OS from Grub2(Ubuntu, Win7,Win10)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I had a dual boot windows7/ubuntu. I have upgraded to windows 10. I had to fix the boot option for windows. This has removed the grub so I had to follow [restore Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd). Now I have 3 options in my grub:

- Ubuntu (and the advances option for ubuntu
- Windows sda2
- Windows sda3

I would like to remove Windows sda2 (Windows7) from Grub.

All the post I have seen talk about completely removing Windows from the Grub, but I would like to keep Windows 10 and Ubuntu in the Grub.

Comment: The Windows entries in the grub menu are created when running `update-grub` or `grub-mkconfig`. The file `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`is used to create these entries. You can disable this by changing the file to not being executable (`sudo chmod 640 /etc/30_os-prober`) or by defining `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER` in `/etc/default/grub`. As this disables the automatic creation of Windows entries in the grub menu, you would have to define them by copying the respective Windows menu definition from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to the end of `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`.

Comment: @ridgy Please add that as answer. :)